# The banner for new users comes back on every reload after dismissing it

Tags: bug, design, anonymous-visitors

I just noticed that the behaviour of the banner shown to new users explaining the site doesn't stay dismissed when you reload the homepage. I'm talking about the banner that looks like this:

[image]

As far as I remember, this used to stay hidden after you dismissed the banner, for as long as your session is remembered. And it really does not make any sense at all to handle it this way, so I assume this is a bug.

I tried this on two sites as an anonymous user, and it happened on both reproducibly. Just open the site, dismiss the banner, and then either reload the homepage or navigate to a post and then back to the homepage.